# ajaxSubmit return data append

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to make an upload picture gallery using ajax . I am using the ajaxSubmit of the ajax form .. Here is what i am doing

```
            $(this).ajaxSubmit({
                target: '#picture',
                success:  afterSuccess 
            });
```

but what this does is that it removes the previous html in the div and replaces it with the new return data. what i want is to append the new image with the previous data in the #picture div . Please help me out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `append` function, `success: function(data) { $("#div").append(data); }`.

Comment: i didn't get you . if i remove the target and do it like the way you are saying , the ajax system doesn't work . I need to append the return data but when i do target: '#picture', it replaces the whole previous data

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice the `target` attribute. Simply do something like `success: function(data) { $("#div").append(data); }`. Of course if the data is in JSON or XML format, you should format it to make it a HTML segment before appending.

Comment: ok .. this part helps but what should i do with the target attribute ? target to none ?

Comment: You don't need the `target` attribute, just remove it! That's not mandatory.